# Converting from Forge externalId into IfcGuid [model-derivative-api]

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-model-derivative, ifc

References:

https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/02/uniqueid-dwf-and-ifc-guid.html

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-model.derivative-nodejs-xls.exporter

https://gist.github.com/jsdbroughton/8ead390ad03f9e26658a80f461276472

Following the sample “bim360appstore-model.derivative-nodejs-xls.exporter” I’m able to export the metadata from a BIM360 model. Each forgeObject has a property “externalId” in format 8-4-4-4-12-8. I need to convert this into the IfcGuid (22 characters long).

When using Revit C# API I have to call

```
 Guid elemGuid = ExportUtils.GetExportId(element.Document, element.Id);

 String ifcGuid = IfcGuid.ToIfcGuid(elemGuid);
```

to get the ifcGuid. How can I do the same using JavaScript in Forge environment?

I tried it, using the JS code from J. Broughton from the references above, but the input data for function fromFullToCompressed() is a 8-4-4-4-12 value, and not the 8-4-4-4-12-8 externalId.

So how to do the first step converting from externalId to elemGuid?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the IFC model is processing by the Navisworks translation pipeline. Consequently, the external id is following the rule of the Navisworks. It's the node path of the selection tree, see my answer here for the detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56985615/7745569

To search for items by `IfcGUIDs` in the Forge Viewer, you can execute a custom PropertyDb query:

```
// Assume there are two IFC Guids: 2cgXCjpDT0ZxBvxMSr3pfm, 0LKJKCHUL1kBtnlFXddz6a

function userFunction( pdb, idVals ) {
    const attrName = 'IfcGUID';

    // Now iterate over all parts to find out which one is the largest.
    const result = [];

    pdb.enumObjects(( dbId ) => {
        // For each part, iterate over their properties.
        pdb.enumObjectProperties( dbId, ( attrId, valId ) => {
            const def = pdb.getAttributeDef( attrId );

            const propName = def.name;
            const displayName = def.displayName;

            if( propName === attrName || displayName === attrName ) {
                const value = pdb.getAttrValue( attrId, valId );
                if( idVals.includes( value ) ) {
                    result.push( dbId );
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    // Return results
    return result;
}

NOP_VIEWER.model.getPropertyDb().executeUserFunction( userFunction, [ '2cgXCjpDT0ZxBvxMSr3pfm', '0LKJKCHUL1kBtnlFXddz6a' ] ).then( ( result ) => console.log( result ) )
```

**Note.** The IFC model must be processed by the **Revit based IFC translation pipeline**, so please check instruction here to switch loader: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change

Hope it helps.

Cheers,

Comment: What is the meaning of displayName === displayName?
This is always true. Or have I misunderstood that?

Comment: Oh, my apologies, it's `displayName === attrName `