# Autodesk Forge API to get "Selection Sets" from SVH2

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-navisworks

Intratech's "Smart3D DBX to NWC" software exports NWC from S3D with embeded "Selection Sets".
In Navisworks, it works fine.
However I couldn't find a way to retrieve "Selection Sets" from SVH2 with Forge API.
Am I missing something ?
[image: Selection Sets from Smart3D DBX]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry that the selection set is not supported currently since no other model formats support it. So, I would advise you to use Naivasworks API to extract the selection set out and store it somewhere, then host a Web API service to serve such data.

If you want to know how to map elements between viewer and Navisworks, please check my answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56985615/7745569

Comment: As you can see in the image, we have created Grid System from Smart3D. and Grid System works fine in Navisworks, but when uploaded to ACC, there is no extension for the grid system. is Grid not supported ?

Comment: Grids are extracted in the AEC model data if the model is translated after June, 2022. then you can show the grid by this sample extension: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/tree/dev/public/extensions/AecGridsExtension